# Why is the binary GCD algorithm so much slower for me?

Tags: ruby, performance, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm

According to Wikipedia it's supposed to be a wee bit faster than Euclid's algorithm (not much, but I was at least expecting to get equal performance). For me it is an order of magnitude slower. Could you guys help me figure out why?

I tried implementing it in Ruby. First I went with a recursive solution

```
def gcd_recursive(u, v)
return u|v if u==0 or v==0

if u.even?
  if v.even?
    return gcd(u>>1, v>>1)<<1
  else
    return gcd(u>>1, v) if v.odd?
  end
elsif u.odd? and v.even?
  return gcd(u, v>>1)
else
  if u < v
    u, v = v, u
  end
  return gcd((u-v)>>1, v)
end
end
```

That didn't work that well, so I wanted to check how fast it would be if it was a loop

```
def gcd(u, v)
  return u|v if u==0 or v==0
  shift=0
  while ((u|v)&1)==0 do
    u=u >> 1;
    v=v >> 1;
    shift += 1
  end
  while ((u&1) == 0) do 
    u=u >> 1
  end
  begin
    while ((v & 1) == 0) do
      v=v >> 1
    end

    if u < v
      v -= u
    else
      diff = u - v
      u = v
      v = diff
    end
  end while v != 0
  u<<shift
end
```

These are the benchmark results

```
       user     system      total        real
std  0.300000   0.000000   0.300000 (  0.313091)
rbn  0.850000   0.000000   0.850000 (  0.872319)
bin  2.730000   0.000000   2.730000 (  2.782937)
rec  3.070000   0.000000   3.070000 (  3.136301)
```

std is the native ruby 1.9.3 C implementation.

rbn is basically the same thing (Euclid's algorithm), but written in Ruby.

bin is the loop code you see above.

rec is the recursive version.

EDIT: I ran the benchmark up there on matz' ruby 1.9.3. I tried running the same test on Rubinius and this is what I got. This is also confusing...

```
 rbn  1.268079   0.024001   1.292080 (  1.585107)
 bin  1.300082   0.000000   1.300082 (  1.775378)
 rec  1.396087   0.000000   1.396087 (  2.348785)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but I suspect it's a combination of two reasons:

1. The binary GCD algorithm is more complex than Euclid's algorithm, and involves lower-level operations, so it suffers more from interpretation overhead when implemented in a high-level language like Ruby.
2. Modern computers tend to have fast division (and modulo) instructions, making the standard Euclidean algorithm hard to compete with.

Comment: This is almost certainly #1 and almost certainly not #2.  If most computers have fast division and modulo instructions, then all computers have very fast shift instructions, many with single cycle implementations.

Comment: bcr, I'm not sure sure... check out my little "edit". I also did some experiments on how rubinius and matz ruby handle xor and AND. turns out matz is way faster with xors and rubinius is much faster with and operations. https://gist.github.com/1297201

Comment: [This](http://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf) says 77-191 clocks per 64-bit DIV; much slower than I was expecting! Bignum performance (e.g. with GMP) would be interesting to look at, as would hand-tuned assembly, but I'm not *that* bored. Memory allocation is another potential overhead, especially if you use bignums.

Comment: Am I wrong or everything is writing just here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#Efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

On modern consumer-grade hardware (M1 Mac Mini, AMD Ryzen 5600X), there seem to be some cases where Euclid's algorithm outperforms and some cases where Binary GCD outperforms. I don't think this has anything to do with Ruby, as I'm using Go. Some cases I found where the two differ significantly in performance, with 64-bit integers:

| m | n | Binary | Euclid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 360 | 92822 | 14.2 ns/op | 9.6 ns/op |
| 123456789 | 987654321 | 29.3 ns/op | 3.8 ns/op |
| 9223372036854775806 | 9223372036854775807 | 129.5 ns/op | 3.8 ns/op |
| 63245986 | 102334155 | 27.1 ns/op | 120.4 ns/op |
| 614889782588491410 | 693386350578511590 | 4.8 ns/op | 6.6 ns/op |

First row is a small composite number and a prime+1. Second row is just the digits in order then reversed. Third row is 2<sup>63</sup>−2 and 2<sup>63</sup>−1. Fourth row is two consecutive Fibonacci numbers. Fifth row is two large products of (mostly) sequential primes (2×3×5×···).

My general observation is that Binary GCD is ever so *slightly* faster than Euclid's algorithm in common cases but they trade off trouncing each other in pathological cases.

I ran the benchmarks a few times and the results were fairly stable. As with any microbenchmark, the numbers are merely illustrative.